# Cannot Copy Text With Dynamically Created Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function for copying a string of text:

```
function copyText(str) {
    console.log(str);
    let tmp = $('<input type="text">').appendTo(document.body);
    tmp.val(str.toString() );
    tmp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    tmp.remove();
}
```

This function works fine, both when called from the console and when called from a button press.

I have a function that copies a color:

```
function copyColor(elm) {
    let hex = $(elm.parentElement).find('span').html();
    console.log('copyText("' + hex + '")' );
    copyText(hex);
}
```

This function is called when a button is pressed. The button passes itself as the parameter. I am dynamically creating the buttons (each one represents a new "color item"). Here is the HTML that is dynamically inserted with jQuery:

```
'<button class="btn copy-btn no-color" title="Copy" data-toggle="popover" onclick="copyColor(this);"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button>'
```

The whole thing is:

```
    $('#' + mode + '-modal .modal-body').prepend(
        '<div class="' + mode + '-item color-item">'
    +       '<button class="btn open-btn no-color" title="Open Color" data-toggle="popover" onclick="openColor(this, \'' + mode + '\');"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></button>'
    +       '<input class="form-control color-name" type="text" placeholder="Name your color (optional)" value="' + name + '">'
    +       '<br class="mobile-only">'
    +       '<div class="color-preview" style="background-color:' + hex + ';"></div>'
    +       '<span>' + hex + '</span>'
    +       '<button class="btn copy-btn no-color" title="Copy" data-toggle="popover" onclick="copyColor(this);"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></button>'
    +       '<button class="btn link-btn no-color" title="Get Link" data-toggle="popover" onclick="copyColorLink(this);"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></button>'
    +       '<button class="btn delete-btn no-color" title="Remove" data-toggle="popover" onclick="removeColor(this);"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>'
    +       '<i class="fas fa-arrows-alt" style="cursor:move;" title="Drag to Change Order" data-toggle="popover"></i>'

    // +        '<button onclick="copyText(\'hi\')">hi</button>'

    +   '</div>'
    );
```

where `mode`, `hex`, and `name` are all parameters in this function.

Every time I click to copy the color, it calls the `copyColor()` function, gets the correct string, calls the `copyText()` function, gets the correct string, and runs with no errors, however it fails to edit my clipboard. When calling this function from the console, with the exact same string, it works, and when creating a static button to copy the color, for example:

`<button onclick="copyText('hi')">hi</button>`

then it works fine as well.  I have also tried dynamically adding one of these buttons:

`+        '<button onclick="copyText(\'hi\')">hi</button>'` to my code that injects HTML, and it does *not* work.

Other dynamically created buttons seen above also call functions and pass themselves as a parameter and work fine, for example the delete button, calling the `removeColor()` function with `this` as the parameter.

Lastly, I've tried giving the buttons dynamic IDs, by way of:

`'<button id="copy-btn-'+ nextID +'"` etc...

Where `nextID` is a value I increment, and I add the onclick listener for that specific button immedatly after creating it:

```
$('#copy-btn-'+nextID).click(function() {
    copyText('hello');
});
nextID++;
```

I've tried creating a new copy function that only takes in the string, and instead of passing an element I just pass the string to be copied:

```
function copyColorNew(hex) {
    console.log('copyText("' + hex + '")' );
    copyText(hex);
}
```

and here is the relevant part of the inserted button code:

```
onclick="copyColorNew(\''+hex+'\');">
```

and it calls the function correctly, passes the correct arguments, and fails to copy the string.

I don't have any duplicate function names, all files are included correctly, I've hard refreshed the page, all variables are in their respective scope, and I've never got any errors. I've also omitted dozens of other rather inconclusive experiments I've done.

I am completely out of ideas, and I've spent several hours a day for several days on this problem. I am well aware how to copy a string in javascript, I'm well aware of how to create a button and append it dynamically, and I'm well aware of how to give the button an onclick listener that passes itself as a parameter. I've had no problems with these things in the past and I still do not everywhere else in this code as I've detailed above.

The only thing I can think of is it's a security problem to allow dynamically created DOM elements to call functions that access the clipboard, but I'm not even pasting the data.

Once again, buttons in the static HTML page can correctly copy 'hello world', dynamically inserted ones cannot copy 'hello world'.

Comment: What ``openColor()`` function does? I read and reread it a few times, and from the tests I've done so far, I found no errors. Could you provide a working snippet?

Comment: @Azametzin `openColor()` works fine and has no errors, like the rest of the code. It simply opens the color in the main view. It's irrelevant to the bug I'm having, as that code works fine and does not interact with the problem code whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

By using the clipboard API (suggested by u/elmstfreddie on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/fbpj53/bizarre_bug_im_having_dynamically_created_buttons/)):

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(hex);
```

I got it to work. I replaced `copyText(hex);` with `navigator.clipboard.writeText(hex);` in my `copyColor()` function.

[Here is the link to the docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api).